# Xcode 4.3 build directory different per configuration?

Tags: xcodebuild, xcode4.3

I took great pains to make sure Xcode 4.3 was the only version of Xcode on my system.

I created a new project (with Git and unit tests). To this project I added a new configuration, copied from Debug, called 'Coverage'. In the project (not 'main target', but 'project') I enabled 'test on build' for the Coverage configuration. In the main target, I enabled both 'test coverage' and 'instrument program flow' for the Coverage configuration.

I also added a new scheme, copied from the only other scheme, called 'Coverage' as well. The only difference in this scheme is checking the 'run' box for the test project in the build action.

I have not changed the DerivedData location in Xcode's preferences.

Okay, that's the setup.

When I run `xcodebuild -configuration Coverage -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme Coverage build`, the output goes to the `DerivedData` folder as expected and code coverage data is created as expected (after tweaking a script in Xcode, something about `TEST_HOST`).

When I run `xcodebuild -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator build`, the output goes to the `build` directory in the project root. Same with `xcodebuild -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos build`.

How can I get these standard configurations to generate artifacts in the 'correct' (DerivedData) folder?

Bonus question: is there a better way to fix that `TEST_HOST` thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that `xcodebuild` requires a `-workspace` argument to normalize the builds in the `DerivedData` folder.

Bonus answer (about `TEST_HOST`):

There is a dichotomy between 'Logic' tests and 'Application' tests that I, as a new iOS developer, was unaware of. If the class you want to test is a subclass of some UI class, that is an 'Application' test and must be run on an actual device. Otherwise (derived from an NS class), that test may be run on a simulator. Simulated tests require an empty `TEST_HOST`.

Oh, and you'll want to add each class you want to test directly to your test target's `Build Sources` phase under `Build Phases` manually, because *that's* not going to slip your mind, ever.

**Seriously**, if someone knows a better way, please comment, or I'll have to accept my own response as an answer. Please comment also if the information presented is erroneous, which it probably is.

You have 72 hours. [calmly pets long-haired white cat]